# In which scene does the uncredited demon character appear?

Tags: character, credits, the-ninth-gate

After reviewing the [IMDB cast list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142688/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) for the movie [The Ninth Gate](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142688/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), I noticed there was an uncredited "demon" character played by [Jane Bradbury](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0102896/). I just recently watched the movie, and have seen it several times before, yet I do not recall seeing this woman or any "demon" character other than possibly "The Girl" who protected Corso, and "The Girl" was played by [Emmanuelle Seigner](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0782561/), so I know it wasn't her. So, the question is where was this "demon" character in the movie?

Comment: she may have received credit for her work, but had her work cut from final version of the film.

Answer (score 1):

You can only see this demon in the director's cut version of the movie. You can also see it in deleted scenes.

When you are looking at the unique scenes in the director's cut it is scene #4.

Comment: Any more information about this director's cut or those deleted scenes?

Comment: Other than that no.

Comment: So you haven't seen them yourself either?

Comment: I haven't seen the demon in the movie. Only in the directors cut.

Comment: And still you can't provide at least the slightest information about the scene in which it appears, i.e. when it happens in the movie, what happens, or anything?

Comment: Oh ya sure let me work that into the answer.

Comment: I can't seem to find a Director's Cut version of the movie. How do you know it was in the Director's Cut? Do you know where one can find a copy of the Director's Cut?

Comment: @druciferre I bought mine on ebay for $35.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't accept this as an answer yet. I've looked everywhere for any evidence of there being a Director's Cut and still can't find any. Normally, in the *Technicial Specs* section of the IMDB article it tells you the different versions (e.g. [Stargate](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111282/technical?ref_=tt_dt_spec)), but only one version is listed for [The Ninth Gate](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142688/technical?ref_=tt_dt_spec) *Technical Specs*. I've looked on eBay and many other stores as well, and found no Director's Cut version.

Comment: @druciferre You don't need to accept it. As long as I helped you that's enough for me.

Comment: *"Oh ya sure let me work that into the answer."* - *"When you are looking at the unique scenes in the director's cut it is scene #4."* - No, that is certainly not a description, but nevermind, I realize that we're not going to see much light here.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - http://www.dvdcompare.net/comparisons/film.php?fid=387 No mention of any deleted scenes or directors cut in 30+ versions of the DVD. -1 for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Jane Bradbury plays only one short scene in the almost end of the movie when corso and girl are near the burning castle and we see Emmanuelle Seigner and fire behind her. just a moment before end of the Sequence the face of the girl change to Jane face.
[image]

Comment: I rewatched the sceen you described. I never saw her face change?

Comment: IIRC her face *does* change a bit, but it's just Seigner in creepy makeup. Why do you think this is Bradbury? Can you back this up with references or pics, maybe?

Comment: @Walt I edited answer and added a picture.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember her changing to another woman. But the problem is that [this doesn't look like Bradbury at all](http://images.fashionmodeldirectory.com/model/000000063581-jane_bradbury-fit.jpg). So now there seems to be another mystery... Who's *that* woman? :O

Comment: I'm sure she is Bradbury. Maybe the picture have been taken not in exact moment( through transition of seigner to bradbury) and she look a little unfammiliar